# How do I grab data after the second time an _ appears in the field in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, character

So here is my code:

```
SELECT d.Args, c.Entered
FROM MailServer.dbo.Messages2Send d (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN MailServer.dbo.ClickLog c (nolock) ON d.id = c.eMsgID
    where d.Date2Send >= '07/19/2013'
    and d.MessageTemplateNameRaw = 'Email.htm'
    and d.Destination NOT LIKE '%@company.com' and d.Destination NOT LIKE '%test%'
    ORDER BY d.Date2Send DESC
```

Output Sample:

```
Args:
pSendInfo=VJ_13710731_V_000003295572
pSendInfo=VJ_13563134_V_000002649396
pSendInfo=VJ_13746113_V_000003553672
pSendInfo=VJ_13894398_V_000004219019
pSendInfo=VJ_13839988_V_000003968856
```

My question is how do I grab everything after the second underscore _ for a desired output.
For Example instead of...
pSendInfo=VJ_13710731_V_000003295572

I just want it to display...
V_000003295572

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there only ever be three _ characters, or could there be more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try (assuming '**_*V*_**' is a constant feature)

```
   select RIGHT( args, LEN(args)-CHARINDEX('_V_', args)-3)
```

**EDIT**

how about passing the index to the first to a another call to charindex to find the second "_"

```
   select RIGHT(args, LEN(args)- ( CHARINDEX('_', args, CHARINDEX('_', args)+1)))
```

Definition of CharIndex from TechNet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

```
   CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

**Arguments**

- expressionToFind
       Is a character expression that contains the sequence to be found. expressionToFind is limited to 8000 characters.
- expressionToSearch
  Is a character expression to be searched.
- start_location
  Is an integer or bigint expression at which the search starts. If start_location is not specified, is a negative number, or is 0, the search starts at the beginning of expressionToSearch.

Basically in order of processing, we find the value of the first underscores location using charindex (2nd call to `CHARINDEX('_', args)` ), plus one and use the new index to charindex's last parameter (`start_location` of 1st call ) to find the second underscore we have the length of the string from start to the second underscore, this is subtracted from the entire string length and presto you have the remainder of the string length then returns the right portion of this string by length.

Comment: Tried this:
select right( d.args, LEN(d.args)-CHARINDEX('_V_', d.args)-3)
FROM MailServer.dbo.Messages2Send d (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN MailServer.dbo.ClickLog c (nolock) ON d.id = c.eMsgID
    where d.Date2Send >= '07/19/2013'
    and d.MessageTemplateNameRaw = 'Email.htm'
    and d.Destination NOT LIKE '%@company.com' and d.Destination NOT LIKE '%test%'
    ORDER BY d.Date2Send DESC

got this error code: Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Also to note that after the second underscore _ it's not alwasy V_following a number it often times is _SCREENNAME

Comment: Very nice! select RIGHT(args, LEN(args)- ( CHARINDEX('_', args, CHARINDEX('_', args)+1))) worked! Thanks.

Comment: Can you break that down for me?